# How can I simplify the these two methods, they are very look-a-like?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have the following code clones:

```
public ArrayList<Short> getShortList(ArrayList<Number> numberList) {
    ArrayList<Short> shortList = new ArrayList<Short>();
    for(Number n : numberList) {
        shortList.add((Short)n);
    }
    return shortList;
}

public ArrayList<Long> getLongList(ArrayList<Number> numberList) {
    ArrayList<Long> longList = new ArrayList<Long>();
    for(Number n : numberList) {
        longList.add((Long)n);
    }
    return longList;
}
```

How can I make one function of these methods? I have trouble in passing the type of an ArrayList as an argument.

Comment: Title says three, but you only posted two

Comment: [Generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/).

Comment: Do you understand that these methods can throw a `ClassCastException` at runtime if misused?

Comment: Not directly related, but don't return ArrayList<Short> - return List<Short> (interface vs implementation). BTW, list.addAll() actually does that, so you could remove both methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would be the generic way to achieve the desired behavior:

```
public <T> List<T> getList(List<? super T> numberList, Class<T> clazz) {
    List<T> longList = new ArrayList<T>();
    for(Object n : numberList) {
        longList.add(clazz.cast(n));
    }
    return longList;
}
```

Note that the method can throw a `ClassCastException` if misused.

Here's an example of how to use the method:

```
List<Number> listNumber = new ArrayList<Number>();
listNumber.add(5L);
listNumber.add(10L);
listNumber.add(25L);
List<Long> listLong = getList(listNumber, Long.class);
System.out.println(listNumber);
System.out.println(listLong);
//this line will throw CastClassException because elements in listNumber are Long only
List<Short> listShort = getList(listNumber, Short.class);
System.out.println(listShort);
```

Comment: There will come a moment when the resulting ArrayList<T> should be casted to an ArrayList<Short> or an ArrayList<Long>, and then I need these methods there?

Comment: @n00b1990 provided a code showing the benefits and pitfalls of this approach.

Comment: Thanks for your help Luiggi, I appreciate it. Shouldn't the arraylist in the method be a List, as that's the return type?

Comment: @n00b1990 `ArrayList` implements `List` interface, that's why the code compiles. But yes, it is better if the variable is declared as `List` as well. Updating the code.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
public <T extends Number> List<T> getList(List<Number> list) {
    List<T> otherList = new ArrayList<T>();
    for(Number n : list) {
        otherList.add((T) n);
    }
    return otherList;
}
```

This code may throw `ClassCastException` for some cases, for example when one of the `Number`s in argument cannot be cast to the type intended by context where you call this method, like this:

```
List<Number> argument = new ArrayList<Number>();
argument.add(5.0);
List<Integer> list = getList(argument);
```

Comment: You missed the `Number` as Parameter.

Comment: The parameter of the method is `List<Number>` but the return type is `List<Long>`. So your proposed method is not the same.

Comment: At least make `T extends Number`.

Comment: I think it would be better if most of the `ArrayList`s would be `List`s. And the parameter would be `List<? super Number>`. An interface with List<Number> can be pain to use.

Comment: why should the parameter be `List<? super Number`>

Comment: So you can pass `List<Object>` as argument.

Comment: @Absurd-Mind Luiggi already posted that "way", I think I'll leave it with <Number> as an alternative.